# Updating Cesium Callback Property causes the entity to flash

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Here is some code that can be pasted into a Cesium Sandcastle.

It adds an entity to the map, then every second, updates the CallbackProperty for the position property. Each time it is updated the entity flashes.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var position = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-114.0, 40.0, 300000.0);
var constant = false;
var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Blue box',
    position: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(getPos, constant),
    box : {
        dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian3(400000.0, 300000.0, 500000.0),
        material : Cesium.Color.BLUE
    }
});

function getPos() {
    return position;
}

function setPosCallback() {
    constant = !constant;
    blueBox.position.setCallback(getPos, constant);
}

setInterval(setPosCallback, 1000);
```

Is there a way to update this type of property without causing the entity to flash? Maybe using requestAnimationFrame or something?

I need to use the callbackProperties for drawing shapes, but once they are drawn, I want them to use constant properties. I have also tried changing the isConstant property, but its read only.

Comment: Removed my answer as I did indeed misread your question - did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @bradimus No, not yet. Replacing the CallbackPropertys with constant ones has increased the performance of my app significantly, but there is a quick flash during the change.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was from a long time ago, but it looks like the problem is this line "constant = !constant;". Simply removing this will fix the flickering.

Edit: I misunderstood the question, I too have the flicker issue when switching between constants and callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately it’s not really an answer. This code snippet here is to show that changing a shapes rendering from constant to not constant results in a flash. The goal was to use constant false while a user draws a shape, the constant true after to increase performance.

Comment: @Zac Oops, sorry! Also, I see in the comments above that you switch between constant and callbacks to improve performance. This is what I'm doing as well and I also get the flash. Maybe there's no fix to it! Cesium's API and docs are pretty terrible.

Answer (score -1):

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var position = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-114.0, 40.0, 300000.0);
var constant = true;
var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Blue box',
    position: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(getPos, constant),
    box : {
        dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian3(400000.0, 300000.0, 500000.0),
        material : Cesium.Color.BLUE
    }
});

var count = -114.0;
function getPos() {
count+=0.2;
    return new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(count, 40.0, 300000.0);
}

function setPosCallback() {
    constant = !constant;
    blueBox.position.setCallback(getPos.bind(blueBox), true);
}

setInterval(setPosCallback, 1000);
```

hi, the box is moving and it didnt flash in my browser when i bind the callback function to the entity and kept constant = true.

you might want to try again. cheers

Comment: I am looking for the performance benefit of using constant = false, there is no point in changing the callback in this example.

Comment: This answer is completely useless as it has no explanation as to what it is and how it addresses the issue (if at all).